# Is there any way to get owner information from device or sim card? Android

Tags: android

I am newbie develop Android application and now I want create and application. So I want to know is there any ways to display Name, Job, Email, Career ... anythings from device or sim card?

Any help much appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: As far as I know, NO. **Luckily**! Just info like name, email and phone. And it's even too much, for my tastes.

Comment: @ArtooDetoo : Okay, so why you know that? If I want get name, email, phone by device or sim card, How I can do that?

Comment: See Niza Siwale's answer

Answer (score 0):

you can get the users name,email etc by using the google plus android API

http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/plus.html